# Planned Contrasts using Multcomp in R

Tags: r, lsmeans

I have an analysis i'd like to perform and I have planned out contrasts (not posthoc comparisons!) I would like to make between treatment groups. The treatment group variable has (k =) 4 levels. I plan to make a total of 3 different comparisons, and therefore,—if I understand correctly—I do not need to make any adjustments to the p-values that are calculated since the comparisons are k-1.

I would like to use the `multcomp` or `lsmeans` package in R to do this. My question is: Does anyone know if it is possible to do this planned comparison WITHOUT any adjustment made to the confidence intervals (and p-value)? As far as I can tell from the vignettes i've looked at and examples i've seen, the `summary.glht()` function makes an adjustment as the default and it is not clear to me what option would undo this.

If someone requires a reproducible example, they could use this example that I found on http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/testing_contrasts.htm:

```
    library(multcomp)

    hsb <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")

    m1 <- lm(read ~ socst + factor(ses) * factor(female), data = hsb)
    summary(m1)

    K <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0), 1)
    t <- glht(m1, linfct = K)
    summary(t)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see your example, your question is a little strange. At least IMO, If you needn't adjust, you needn't use `multcomp` package (but in some situation, it saves us some time).

```
library(multcomp)
hsb <- read.csv("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsb2.csv")
hsb$ses <- as.factor(hsb$ses)

m3 <- lm(read ~ socst + ses, data = hsb)
l3 <- glht(m3, linfct = mcp(ses = "Tukey"))

# mcp(~) doesn't run with some type of model. If so, you'll give the matrix directly.
# k3 <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 0,
#                0, 0, 0, 1,
#                0, 0, -1, 1), byrow = T, ncol = 4)
# rownames(k3) <- c("2-1", "3-1", "3-2")
# l3 <- glht(m3, linfct = k1)

summary(l3, test=adjusted("none"))    # this is the result without adjustment
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# 2 - 1 == 0   0.6531     1.4562   0.448    0.654
# 3 - 1 == 0   2.7034     1.6697   1.619    0.107
# 3 - 2 == 0   2.0503     1.3685   1.498    0.136

hsb$ses <- relevel(hsb$ses, ref="2")  # change of the order of levels
m3.2 <- lm(read ~ socst + ses, data = hsb)
summary(m3)     # "Without adjustment" means it's equivalent to original model's statistics.
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#  :
# ses2         0.65309    1.45624   0.448    0.654    
# ses3         2.70342    1.66973   1.619    0.107 

summary(m3.2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#  :
# ses3         2.05033    1.36846   1.498    0.136

# When argument is lmer.obj, summary(~, adjusted("none")) returns p.value by using z value with N(0, 1).
```

Comment: Thanks! The `test = adjusted("none"))` is what I was looking for. I know the example I gave was a bit silly, but in my dataset the there are 4 levels and they will be combined and compared in different ways and so the multicomp package seemed like an easy way of doing this without creating a bunch of dummy variables.